# Dropbox downloads next file and then hangs per every start

Tags: sync, downloads, dropbox

I have a strange problem with dropbox on notebook with Ubuntu 13.10 (the problem also existed in Ubuntu 13.04). When I start dropbox, it downloads a single file (it's an ordinary photo, 2-3 mb) and then hangs. The message is "downloading 10 files". I also get the following error in the terminal:

```
(dropbox:22359): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-    2.38.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:2475: signal 'child-added' is invalid for instance '0xa2a4070' of type 'GtkMenu'
```

If I run `dropbox status` it gives `Dropbox isn't responding`.

Then I stop and start dropbox again, it downloads *the next file* and hangs with "downloading 9 files".

So basically I need to restart dropbox to download every next file. Dropbox on my work machine is working fine (the same files). I tried to fully reinstall and reconnect dropbox, it didn't work. Can anyone help?